# Is it possible to have multiple URLs under the Background section - Karate API?

Tags: soap, automation, automated-tests, bdd, karate

As I need to have single **feature file** with multiple scenarios, and each scenario will have different SOAP Request that belongs to various WSDL URL.

So will **Karate API** allow me to put multiple URLs for each scenario?

If Yes, how can I write the script for that? if No, please suggest me the alternative option.

Thanks.

Comment: hey can you accept the answer for this question also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an separate java utility to load all the URLs into an Map and have an another method to return URL when scenario name is given as input(getting value for the key in map).
example code in feature file:

```
Scenario:scenario1
And def URL = Java.type( 'URLReader.java' ) 
And def FirstScenrioURL = URL.getMapValue('scenario1')
Given url FirstScenrioURL
```

Try this one..